# ReactJS post increment does not work in setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

While working with ReactJS setState method to update state I observed that post increment operator was not working(did not get any error as well) so I had to use + 1 instead for the same. Any idea why this behaviour as I am new to React and got shocked to learn this.

Here is my code:
This did not work:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
      left: prevState.left++
}));
```

This worked:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
      left: prevState.left + 1
}));
```

Comment: This is probably the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316556/4810504

Comment: this behaviour is not related to `reactjs` or `javascript`, this is how **post-increment** operator works.

Comment: thanks for your inputs, its so silly on my part to forget the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x++ expression first returns the value of x then it increments it

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  left: ++prevState.left
}));
```

should give the expected result

Comment: instead of `++` better to use `+ 1`, `++` will mutate the origin value :)

Comment: absolutely :) it's always a bad idea to mutate a function's params

Comment: thanks for your inputs, its so silly on my part to forget the basics.

Answer (score 1):

This is javascript, you are asigning the prevState to the prevState value :

```
a = 0; 
a = a++;
a == 0 // true
a++
a == 0 // false
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, its so silly on my part to forget the basics.