# Why do I have to click twice for an event in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var [broj, setBroj] = useState(0);
function plus() {
    setBroj(broj++)
}
function minus() {
    setBroj(broj--)
}
return (<div>
    <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    <h3>{broj}</h3>
    <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
</div>
)
```

when i click first time nothing just after second time work
every 2 time ( onclick ) work

Comment: I'm surprised it works the second time. Doh! I get why now. No re-render means the same `broj` variable is used the second time (and by then it's been updated, by the first click).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS post increment does not work in setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881217/reactjs-post-increment-does-not-work-in-setstate)

Comment: Side note: Use `const` for what you get from `useState`, not `var` or `let`. That can help you avoid direct mutation (of primitives, anyway). (Side note 2: Never use `var`. It has no place in modern JavaScript. :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the state value with `setBroj(broj++)` it doesn't change the state with `broj + 1` value because `++` affects after the code is executed. You should use `setBroj(broj + 1)` instead.

```
var [broj, setBroj] = useState(0);
function plus() {
  setBroj(broj + 1);
}
function minus() {
  setBroj(broj - 1);
}
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    <h3>{broj}</h3>
    <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Cool. If it worked please accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: yes i will just for 3 min   ----   "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes"

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're updating state the wrong way. You're mutating the state directly using `++` and `--` operators which you shouldn't. Following is the correct way :-

```
var [broj, setBroj] = useState(0);
function plus() {
    setBroj(broj=>broj+1)
    //setBroj(broj+1) - this will also work.
}
function minus() {
    setBroj(broj=>broj-1)
   //setBroj(broj-1) - this will also work.
}
return (<div>
    <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    <h3>{broj}</h3>
    <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you post-increment and post-decrement.

Write `setBroj(broj + 1)` and `setBroj(broj - 1)`

Now you could pre-increment and pre-decrement but please don't. You don't need to mutate that variable.