# toggling boolean value in stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a fairly simple stateful component whose value I wish to toggle whenever someone clicks on a button:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  state = {
    sidedrawer: false
  }

  sideDrawerCloseHandler = () => {
    this.setState({sidedrawer: false})
  }

  sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
    this.setState({sidedrawer: !sidedrawer})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Aux>
        <Toolbar sideDrawerTogglerHandler={this.sideDrawerTogglerHandler}/>
        <SideDrawer SideDrawerOpen={this.state.sidedrawer} sideDrawerCloseHandler={this.sideDrawerCloseHandler} />
        <main className={classes.co}>
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
      </Aux>
    )
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Now, when I run my react App it throws an error saying:

> `sidedrawer` is not defined in line 19

Can someone help me in fixing and understanding the error?

The line 18 - 19 happens to be this part in my code

```
sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
  this.setState({sidedrawer: !sidedrawer})
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side drawer isn't defined, what is defined is this.state.sidedrawer, what you are seeking is

```
      sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
           this.setState({sidedrawer: !this.state.sidedrawer})
      }
```

But this isn't the best way to setState, as explained on React docs, the best way to update state based on the previous state is using setState with a function that receives the prevState as a prop, you can try this instead

```
 sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
      sidedrawer: !prevState.sidedrawer 
    }));
   }
```

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837670/reactjs-setstate-previous-state-is-the-first-argument-props-as-the-second-argum/50837784#50837784 or here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html to understand better

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think about this method (this works though but any drawbacks)? `sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
   let sideDrawerToggler = this.state.sideDrawer;
   sideDrawerToggler = !sideDrawerToggler;
  this.setState({sidedrawer: sideDrawerToggler})
  }`

Comment: If a person clicks twice, really fast, both sideDrawerToggler can get their value before the first setState is executed, so maybe, just maybe if he is really fast, you cant get the wrong value. That's why react suggests that way to ensure you will always have the right value

Answer (score 5):

You have to get `sidedrawer` from your state:

```
sideDrawerTogglerHandler = () => {
 this.setState((previousState) => {
   return {sidedrawer: !previousState.sidedrawer}
 })
}
```