# Javascript object elements is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Trying to log the values of *name*, *day* and *dob* elements stored in *dataEdited* as object.Two of the elements display *Undefined* with just one displaying the correct value.
Here is the code

```
/*    two-way state binding   */
dataChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value; //gets value of the textbox
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({ dataEdited: {[name]: value} });
    }
handleUpdate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const {name,day,dob} = this.state.dataEdited;
        console.log(name, day, dob);

        /* this.setState({ toggle: false }) */

    }
```

State

```
this.state = {
            name: '',
            day: '',
            dob: '',
            items : [],
            currentItem: {},
            dataEdited: {},
            toggle: false,
            loading: false
        }
```

Render

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate}>
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    name="name"                             
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.name}
                                    placeholder= "Celebrant's Name" 
                                    ref={name => this.name = name}
                                    required /> 
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    type="number" 
                                    name="day"
                                    min="1" 
                                    max="31"
                                    ref={day => this.day = day}
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.day}
                                    placeholder= "day"  />
                                <input 
                                    className=""
                                    name="dob"
                                    type="month"                                
                                    onChange={this.dataChange}
                                    defaultValue={this.state.currentItem.dob} />

                                <button type="submit">update</button>
                                <button onClick={this.handleEditCancel}>cancel</button>
</form>
```

This is the result on the console

```
undefined undefined "2020-08"
```

I don't understand how this is possible, can I get an explanation. Also, how can I fix this?

Comment: what do you get when you log this.state.dataEdited to the console

Comment: Show the `render` function code

Comment: as mentioned in the question i got *Undefined Undefined "2020-08"*

Comment: can you share `this.setState` code

Comment: `setState({ dataEdited: {[name]: value} })`. You're setting `dataEdited` as an object that only has a single property. React only performs a shallow merge (Object.assign) when setting state, so if you redefine a state value that is an object, you have to spread the old value into the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `this.setState({ dataEdited: {[name]: value} });` you overwrite the other values in the object assigned to `dataEdited`.

You should change that to `this.setState({ dataEdited: { ...this.state.dataEdited, [name]: value} });` to preserve the previous values inside `this.state.dataEdited`

**UPDATE** *(Thanks @JMadelaine)*: You should use `this.setState(prev => ({ dataEdited: { ...prev.dataEdited, [name]: value}}));` to ensure that no concurrent state changes affects the `setState()`

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837784/10201813

Comment: You should pass a function since your new state value depends on the previous value: `this.setState(prev => ({ dataEdited: { ...prev.dataEdited, [name]: value}}));`

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

you are overwriting the same `dataEdited` variable over and over when you call `this.setState({ dataEdited: {[name]: value} });`
Thus only the last  changed data will be present inside dataEdited

### Solution

Seperately save the data or change setState function appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the state variable `dataEdited` everytime you call

```
this.setState({ dataEdited: {[name]: value} });
```

so you want to change spread the object `dataEdited` and the `state` After that add or change the name,dob or day

```
  this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  dataEdited: { ...this.state.dataEdited, [name]: value }
});
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-violet-tiehd)