# useState in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and javascript I just wanna ask if there would be a problem if I will be coding this

```
let [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

// combined with this:

```
setValue((value += 1));
```

//instead of doing this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

//combined with this:

```
setValue((prevState) => {
        return prevState + 1;
      });
```

Thankkkk you so mucccch!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837670/reactjs-setstate-previous-state-is-the-first-argument-props-as-the-second-argum

Comment: Have you had any problems coding the first way?

Comment: No .. it works fine as the setValue((prevState) => {
        return prevState + 1;
      });.  I just wanna know if the the first way could be a substitute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, no issue with it.

```
setValue((prevState) => {
        return prevState + 1;
      });
```

You can also write `setValue(prevState=>prevState+1)` - a short form of getting previous state and updating it.

setValue((value += 1)); this is valid but a better approach would be to take the previous state and update with new.

Comment: Why is `setValue((value += 1));` not valid?

Comment: @user3532758 indeed a valid but here idea is to take the previous state and update with a new one and setValue((value += 1)) doesn't take prev state. Edited my comment which created confusion.