# Value of count in state isn't incrementing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in my app,

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      count:0
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App-header'>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({count:this.state.count=this.state.count++})}}>You Clicked This : {this.state.count} Times.</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

i added an event on this button :

```
<button onClick={()=>{this.setState({count:this.state.count=this.state.count++})}}>You Clicked This : {this.state.count} Times.</button>
```

but when im clicking it, value of count isn't incrementing

ps : im new to react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has more to do with plain old javascript than react and state management.

Below is a small reproduction of your issue:

```js
let y = 2;
y = y++;
console.log(y);
y = ++y;
console.log(y);
```

This is because of how `++` [(increment operator)](If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing.) works.

From the docs:

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the increment operator increments and returns the value before incrementing. If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, ++x), the increment operator increments and returns the value after incrementing.

Also it is note worthy that you should not do anything like:

```
this.state.variable = randomValue;
```

The fix

```
this.setState({count:this.state.count=++this.state.count})
```

will work because

```
this.state.count=++this.state.count
```

return the increment count. But state is actually updated by `this.setState` and you can also do:

```
this.setState({count:++this.state.count})
```

[When new state value is dependent on previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837670/reactjs-setstate-previous-state-is-the-first-argument-props-as-the-second-argum)

Comment: ++this.state.count mutates state directly which is not recommended. Instead callback should be used this.setState(previousState => {count: previousState.count + 1})

Comment: Yes, but that was not the scope of the question. So instead of writing a long explanation I just added a link

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, when updating state, that depends on previous state, you should use callback function in state update which receives previous state and return value is updated state

```
this.setState(previousState => ({count: previousState.count + 1}))
```

Comment: yeah i've tried that