# What is the difference in the below code when using useState() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I understood how useState works. But in some of the tutorial
setItem() is used as one which is not commented in bellow code.

Is there a difference between them.

```
// setItems([...items, item]);
   setItems((prev) => [...prev, item]);
```

```
const [items,setItems] = useState(["Apple","Mango","Milk"]);

const [item, setItem] = useState("");

const addItem = () => {
    // setItems([...items, item]);
    setItems((prev) => [...prev, item]);
    setItem(" ")
  };



<input type="text" value={item} onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)} />
<button onClick={addName}> Add item </button>
```

Comment: What is your question or issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837670/reactjs-setstate-previous-state-is-the-first-argument-props-as-the-second-argum  take a look at this