# Maximum update depth exceeded (without onclick)

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked before, but it doesn't seem to work for me because what I am trying to do is show the `price` without an onClick function.

I am setting the `price` according to planType and billing.

Here is the code:

```
    this.state = {
      planType: "", //populated through componentDiDMount
      billing: "", //populated through componentDiDMount
      price: 0
    };
  }

  renderPrice() {
    if (
      this.state.billing === "Monthly" &&
      this.state.planType === "Start-Up Plan"
    ) {
      this.setState({
        price: this.state.total_invoice + 35
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>You will be charged {this.renderPrice()}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: You cannot call `setState` inside render function

Comment: Is your `values` coming from props ? If so, you can initialize your state using class constructor function.

Comment: It is with class constructor

Comment: Your code can be further optimized with object destructuring. You can also declare your variable first, then use conditional checking to update the variable before calling `setState`, so you don't have to write `setState` multiple times and its easier to read !

Comment: Can you show me an example on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually hesitated to post this answer. This is more like an optimization than the actual answer. But since @oneone asked for it. I will post a general idea on how to improve your code's readability.

One thing to really consider about is, does that `value` really need to be in `state`. If that value is only used to compute some other values, **maybe** you don't have to store it in state. Of course I don't know the actual implementation of the codes so you'll have to figure it out by yourself.

```
class Component extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // Do consider if billing / planType is actually necessary to be in state.
      billing: null,
      planType: null,
      price: 0,
      total_invoice: 0,
    };
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    const { total_invoice } = this.state; 

    const newBilling = 'Monthly';
    const newPlanType = 'Start-Up Plan';

    // default price
    let price = total_invoice;

    this.setState({ billing: newBilling, planType: newPlanType }, () => {
      const { planType } = this.state; 
      // setState callback, state values here are guaranteed to be updated.
      switch (planType) {
        case 'Start-Up Plan':
          price = total_invoice + 35;
          break;
        case 'Standard Plan':
          price = total_invoice + 65;
          break;
        default:
      }
      this.setState({ price });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { price } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        You will be charged {price}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem 100%! I have never seen anyone use the setState somewhere else as you did. Before that, I was getting an error because of two setStates. But now it works like a charm!

Comment: Generally in this type of data changes there really is no need to wait for `billing` and `planType` to change and then try to change the price, if you wait, you are practically calling `setState` two times and causing an extra update when you don't really have!, which i believe is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes. Generally you should only call `setState` once. I am aware that my codes will trigger rerender for two times. Your answer will call `setState` twice too by the way. That's why I have a note in my codes stating that that if `billing` and `planType` is really needed as a state. If it's only for computing other values, maybe you don't need it to be inside a state. Of course in the end it depends on what the author wants to do.

Comment: I did note in my answer that if you call setState inside a function multiple times (without any timeout) like i did in componentDidMount, because the setState doesn't happen instantly, React will combine the result and only does one setState and avoids multiple updates

Answer (score 2):

Never ever `setState` inside render, there is a much better way to do what you are trying to do,
I take it you want the price change happens when the `billing` and the `planType` are set to a specific values, to do this all you need to do is check and `setState` the `price` when and where these two values change!
For example you are saying these two value are getting populated through `componentDidMount`, so you simply need to check their value in that place and set the `price` there!, its as simple as that.
Here is some code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyClass extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        billing: null,
        planType: null,
        total_invoice: 0,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //These can change through api or any other way you want!
        const newBillingType = 'Monthly';
        const newPlanType = 'Start-Up Plan';

        this.setState({ billing: newBillingType, planType: newPlanType })

        if (newBillingType === "Monthly" && newPlanType === "Start-Up Plan") {
            this.setState({ price: this.state.total_invoice + 35 })
        }
    }

    render() {

        return <div>You will be charged {this.state.price}</div>;
    }
}

export default MyClass;
```

**Please note** that if you call `setState` inside a function multiple times (without any timeout) like i did in `componentDidMount`, because the `setState` doesn't happen instantly, `React` will combine the result and only does one `setState` which is a good thing and avoids multiple updates.

Comment: I had tried it before it didn't work, I tried it again and now it works with two setState's. I will update my code so you can see the solution. Thank you!

Comment: @oneone, i added a sample of what i just said, hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Yes, now I got a problem when I change it to another plan, the second setState overrides the number to 35 eveytime.

Comment: @oneone I saw your solution, and it seems you are forgetting that `setState` is not sync! does not happen instantly so if you call `this.state.total_invoice + 35` two times, it doesn't mean `70`, because the value inside `state` is not yet updated

Comment: @oneone There are a lot of answers and question on how to increase something in react, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316376/how-to-use-the-increment-operator-in-react, please try reading some of them so you can get an idea of how react works, good luck

Comment: No, I wasn't duplicating the ```setState``` to achieve ```70``` . I was duplicating it because it just works that way. I updated my code with another planType check and that's when it shows ```35``` instead of ```65``` and I am a beginner in React I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: @oneone I suggest you take a look at https://codesandbox.io/ and write your examples and codes there, this enabled you to share your samples with us and we can help you or even correct your code easily.