# Why can't I use increment operators with useState?

Tags: reactjs, state, increment, use-state

I've recently jumped into studying react and encountered this trouble.
Why can't I use increment operators when changing the state?

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const changeNum = () => {
    setNum(num + 1)
  } 
  return (
    <div>
      <i className='xi-heart' onClick={changeNum}></i> {num}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to count the number of clicks.
When I use increment operator num++ instead of num + 1, it's not working.
have been researching for the answer and found some ([How to use the increment operator in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316376/how-to-use-the-increment-operator-in-react/39316556#39316556)) but still don't understand.
You should never mutate the state. Okay.
Then How does num++ mutate the state directly but num+1 does not?

Comment: num++ returns the same value. See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#description

Comment: You technically could use `num++` if you declared the variable with `let` instead of `const`, and then passed the result to `setNum` - but it'd be easier to use preincrement instead - or, even better, make things less confusing and simply pass the number plus one, instead of also incrementing the state variable (which is really weird, although not entirely forbidden)